# Historical connection between CVS and SVN

Tags: svn, client-server, cvs, dvcs

At some point, as a younger IT person I learned that there was some connection between CVS and the more recent version control system SVN. Months and years later, I tried to rediscover the connection, and I came up with nothing. So I thought that maybe I was making something up in the past. Searching a little harder, I found info stating that Subversion (SVN) was started by former CVS developers. What's the story on this? Why not update CVS? Why did the CVS devs start over with SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Subversion book:

> In early 2000, CollabNet, Inc. (http://www.collab.net) began seeking developers to write a replacement for CVS. CollabNet offered[3] a collaboration software suite called CollabNet Enterprise Edition (CEE), of which one component was version control. Although CEE used CVS as its initial version control system, CVS's limitations were obvious from the beginning, and CollabNet knew it would eventually have to find something better. Unfortunately, CVS had become the de facto standard in the open source world largely because there wasn't anything better, at least not under a free license. So CollabNet determined to write a new version control system from scratch, retaining the basic ideas of CVS, but without the bugs and misfeatures.

To keep reading: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.history